# Бесперебойная работа сайта

Tags: домен, dns, хостинг

Необходимо обеспечить беспрерывную доступность сайта вне зависимости от проблем с инетом или DDoS у какого-то одного выбранного хостера. Выбрать самого лучшего хостера со 100% доступностью или купить хостинг в 2х разных компаниях и сделать round-robin DNS? Но ведь при падении одного из 2х серверов в round-robin - 50% клиентов будут перенаправлены на него, т.е. на упавший сервер и пока обновятся записи в DNS...пройдет время и за это время вполне возможно будет восстановлен доступ к упавшему серверу. Кто что может посоветовать для решения данной проблемы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Может лучше облачный хостинг, сразу амазона?

Comment: а как в облачных технологиях реализован failover в случае падения одного интернет канала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Выбрать самого лучшего хостера со 100% доступностью или купить хостинг в 2х разных компаниях и сделать round-robin DNS?

Вы думаете, что у хостера какие-то особенные серваки, которые от вашего приложения не лягут, а vps - лягут?

> Но ведь при падении одного из 2х серверов в round-robin - 50% клиентов будут перенаправлены на него

Увидят, что он недоступен и запросят айпишник заново

> и пока обновятся записи в DNS...

Зачем их вообще обновлять? Даже в самом худшем случае нужно будет ребутнуть и просто превратить в прокси, но это если не реализован следующий вариант:

Ставится 2+ балансировщика нагрузки, на которые и указывают записи DNS, а эти балансировщики уже выбирают реальные сервера бэкенда, при этом эти балансировщики могут вообще смотреть на одни и те же сервера, просто дублируя друг друга.

В 99% случаев хватает и простого дублирования серваков или вообще одного сервака. Failsafe - оно, конечно, приятно, но пока нет жестких причин для внедрения, можно заниматься более интересными вещами. Серваки падают обычно не просто так, а из-за нагрузки, и такие проблемы все-таки с обратной стороны решаются.

**Обновление**

Балансировщик я посоветовал потому, что он "увидит" упавший сервер и выбросит его на какое-то время из пула серверов. Основной род деятельности у него другой, но от таких штук защитит.

Comment: Ну, в нашем случае серваки чаще всего падают только из-за хостера, а не из-за нагрузки, как раз нагрузка всегда слабая и приложения достаточно неплохо оптимизированы. 

И нужен по сути не балансировщик нагрузки, а какое-то решение, которое позволит быть независимым от хостера, у которого инет упал или еще что-то.

Comment: Но доступ к этому балансировщику также должен быть бесперебойным. А если у хостера проблемы с каналом, балансировщик станет недоступным, и вся архитектура рухнет. В случае с round robin DNS, насколько я понял, пользователи будут переброшены на другой ip...

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) бесплатный прикрутите и всё будет хорошо )

Весь трафик пойдёт через них, снимается проблема атак, отчасти кэшируется статика. Платные режимы даже в случае падения серверов продолжат показывать кэшированные страницы.

Comment: Ну кешированные страницы - тоже не вариант...